# programming Run command shell with java (SIPp)

Tags: java

If I run this code i didn't figure out any thing on eclipse console but in terminal the program SIPp run normal

```
public class run {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("sipp","-sn", "uas");
        Map<String, String> environment = builder.environment();
        Process javap = builder.start();
        InputStreamReader tempReader = new InputStreamReader(new  BufferedInputStream(javap.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tempReader);
        while (true){
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is you question?

Comment: do you have any exception on while loop?

Comment: no i have any exception

Comment: if i run this code  i didn't figure out any thing on eclipse console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your while loop as following

```
String line;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tempReader);
    while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null){
       System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Hope this will give you an idea.

Comment: there is no result in console eclipse

Comment: sorry friend actually i dont have idea in java. just i suggested.